# Sinch detect SINCall crash

Tags: sinch

Is there a way to detect when the user on the other end of a SINCall crashes? There seems to be no change in state on SINCall.details.endState or SINCall.state.

I'm currently using a hack to listen for a specific message in

`client(client: SINClient!, logMessage message: String!, area: String!, severity: SINLogSeverity, timestamp: NSDate!)`

to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, currently there is no callback triggered when the SINCall crashes on the other end.